# ios8 [view setFrame:rect] not working

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, ios7.1

I am not able to reposition my uiview in ios8 programatically.The following code seems to be working perfectly fine in ios7.1 but is not working in ios8.

This code is inside layoutSubview function of the view.

```
 for (UIView *child in self.subviews)
    {
        if((self.removeOnHide == YES && child.hidden == NO)  || self.removeOnHide == NO) {
            top += self.spacing;
            switch (self.hAlignment)
            {
                case UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft:
                    left = self.leftMargin;
                    break;
                case UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight:
                    left = self.frame.size.width - self.rightMargin
                    - child.frame.size.width;
                    break;
                default: // center
                    left = baseline - child.frame.size.width / 2;
                    break;
            }
            CGRect rect = child.frame;
            child.frame = CGRectMake(left, top, child.frame.size.width,
                                     child.frame.size.height);
            rect = child.frame;

            top += child.frame.size.height;
        }
    }
```

I am using code from this git repos https://github.com/tazihosniomar/LayoutManager. The code use to work perfectly fine in ios7.1 but is not working in ios8.0

Comment: Log `self.vLayoutView`, what is the output? What is this view? When is this code called?

Comment: https://github.com/tazihosniomar/LayoutManager/blob/master/LayoutManager/VLayoutView.m#L35 this is the exact location of the code.

Comment: Fixed it just had to remove the view from autolayout and then it worked..

Comment: @SiddhantJain what do you mean "remove the view from auto layout and then it worked"?

Comment: So the issue was that i had set included a view in auto layout from the interface builder and then was trying to change its properties from the code. Now since it was already in auto layout the changes were not getting reflected.

Comment: Just to continue from @SiddhantJain's comment, you can have AutoLayout and be able to set a UIView's frame via code by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` on the UIView you want to update.